# React dynamic add select input field

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am trying Create a select field dynamically. When clicking the add button, it will dynamically add select fields. I have and issue where the values don't change.

My code can be viewed on codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-field-dynamically-uo4dy?file=/src/App.js

Comment: instead of option.value.target , it should be option.value;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at my changes:

[Forked sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-field-dynamically-forked-gv81p)

```
// I added a 3rd argument for the name:    
const handleRoomChange = (option, index, name) => {
    const value = option.value; // you had this as 'const { value } = option.value' which dereferences value twice
    console.log(value);
    const list = [...roomInputs];
    list[index][name] = value; //you had this as list[index][value]
    setRoomInputs(list);
  };


// onChange passes the name as 3rd argument to handleRoomChange
<Select
   name="boardBasic"
    placeHolder="Board"
    value={options.value}
    onChange={option => handleRoomChange(option, i, "boardBasic")}
    options={options}
    styles={{
        menu: (provided) => ({ ...provided, zIndex: 9999 })
    }}
/>
```

Comment: These changes do fix the problem, but I would recommend changing handleRoomChange's name if it is going to handle both room and board changes, to avoid confusion later on.

Answer (score 1):

You have three problems that I can see.

First, you only have a handleRoomChange function that is trying to handle both room changes and board changes. You should probably have a handleBoardChange function, as well.

Second, if you output `option` to the console inside handleRoomChange, you will notice that `option.value` is a number. So, when you proceed to set `list[index][value]` to  `value`, what you're saying is that you want (for example) `roomInputs[1][1]` to be 1. `roomInputs[1]` has no `1` property, which is why you will end up with the wrong properties inside your object on submission. You need to be setting `roomInputs[1].roomType` to value, instead (and the `boardBasic` property in your handleBoardChange method, when you write it).

Third, you are trying to use object destructuring to assign `object.value` to your `value` variable...but you're trying to destructure `object.value` instead of destructuring `object`. For this reason, `value` is `undefined` every time you run the function. Replace the assignment with `const { value } = option;` and you will start getting defined values back.